# How to replace a special arrow and row in a matrix with a symbol and drop it?

Tags: matrix, filtering

I need to do a iteration, if condition[i] is true, I want to drop i row and i column in the matrix A. To keep the index of A unchanged, I think I should replace i row and i column as zero or other symbol, and then drop them, and finally get a smaller matrix B. So, how to realize it?

For example, A=DiagonalMatrix[Table[i, {i, 1, 10}]], if Sin[i]>0, delete i row and i column, and finally, B is {{4, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 5, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 6, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 9}}.

Comment: This is a bit unclear. What are you trying to do that requires the removal of matrix rows (which is easily done with `Delete[]`)?

Comment: An MWE is appreciated.

Comment: @J.M.issomewhatokay. If I delete a row, the index of A changed, and it's inconvenient to write the condition[i]. So I want to replace it, after the iteration finished, and then delete them.

Comment: That did not answer my question. What are you trying to compute with your matrices that involves deleting rows?

Comment: @J.M.issomewhatokay. For a real system, I need to throw some unneeded freedom degrees.

Comment: It would help a lot if you were to edit your question by adding an example of  the kind of matrix you want to operate on and also show the final result you expect to get from the operations you want to carry out.

Comment: What is "i arrow"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
idxs = Range[10]
A = DiagonalMatrix[idxs] (* your example *)
keeps = Select[idxs, Sin[#] <= 0 &]
A[[keeps, keeps]]
```

Comment: I think it's what I need, may I ask more that I want to know that the mapping between i and j, i,j is the index of matrix A, B respectively.

Comment: @dnvin Here `keeps` is a list of indexes to keep; the others are discarded.  First we select the rows; then we select the columns. In your provided example, you wanted to keep the same rows indexes and column indexes.  (However, this code is easily generalized.)